# How to rescale axes with pcolormesh

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

I am plotting a graph using `pcolormesh`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(Omega_re, Omega_im, brightness, cmap="gray", shading="gouraud")
ax.set_xlabel(r"$Re(\omega)$")
ax.set_ylabel(r"$Im(\omega)$")
ax.set_aspect(1)
fig.show()
```

where

```
Omega_re = array([[2.  , 2.75, 3.5 , 4.25, 5.  ], [2.  , 2.75, 3.5 , 4.25, 5.  ],
       [2.  , 2.75, 3.5 , 4.25, 5.  ], [2.  , 2.75, 3.5 , 4.25, 5.  ],
       [2.  , 2.75, 3.5 , 4.25, 5.  ]])

Omega_im = array([[0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ], [0.0005, 0.0005, 0.0005, 0.0005, 0.0005],
       [0.001 , 0.001 , 0.001 , 0.001 , 0.001 ], [0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015],
       [0.002 , 0.002 , 0.002 , 0.002 , 0.002 ]])

brightness = array([[4.05649772, 3.7299948 , 2.61262439, 4.2841897 , 3.40368949],
                    [4.05649076, 3.72997624, 2.61258381, 4.2841071 , 3.40353591],
                    [4.05648399, 3.72995772, 2.61254052, 4.28402084, 3.40338229],
                    [4.05647716, 3.72993901, 2.6124984 , 4.28393373, 3.40322865],
                    [4.05647025, 3.72992049, 2.61245428, 4.2838476 , 3.40307499]])
```

But since the x-axis ranges from 0 to 5 and the y-axis ranges from 0 to 0.002, the result appears "flattened.":

[image: plot flattedned]

Is there a way to rescale the y-axis so that the graph looks visually better? Below is a picture of how it is currently being displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
ax.set_aspect(1)
```

with

```
ax.set_aspect("auto")
```

or simply remove the line entirely.

[`set_aspect(1)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html) (or equivalently `set_aspect("equal")`) forces the axes to use the same scaling for x and y. Using `set_aspect("auto")` (the default) allows matplotlib to infer a good scaling to fill the plot.

### Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The axes are "flat" because of `ax.set_aspect(1)`, which sets the aspect ratio of the axes to be equal. In other words, 1 inch (for example) is the same length on both axes. If you remove that line then you'll get an automatically-generated aspect ratio that will show more detail.